# How do I create more tables Pythonanywhere

Tags: python, mysql, flask-sqlalchemy

I followed the tutorial to create a simple database-backed flask website. [Here](http://blog.pythonanywhere.com/121/)

I successfully followed the tutorial but I'm struggling to create more than one table using this method. I want the table to be called Ingredient.
Here is my code from flask_app.py

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, render_template, request, url_for
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["DEBUG"] = True

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = "mysql+mysqlconnector://{username}:
{password}@{hostname}/{databasename}".format(
    username="Harrryj",
    password="mypassword",
    hostname="Harrryj.mysql.pythonanywhere-services.com",
    databasename="Harrryj$comments",
)
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_POOL_RECYCLE"] = 299
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS"] = False
db = SQLAlchemy(app)



class Comment(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = "Comment"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    content = db.Column(db.String(100))


@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def index():
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render_template("main_page.html", 
comments=Comment.query.all())

    comment = Comment(content=request.form["contents"])
    db.session.add(comment)
    db.session.commit()
    return redirect(url_for('index'))



class Ingredient(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "Ingredient"

    Ingredient_ID = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    Ingredient_Name = db.Column(db.String(100))
    Ingredient_Calories = db.Column(db.Integer(100))
```

When I try and create the table in the database through the bash console this happens:

```
In [6]: from flask_app import db
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-5825668f6e50> in <module>()
----> 1 from flask_app import db
/home/Harrryj/mysite/flask_app.py in <module>()
     41 
     42 
---> 43 class Ingredient(db.Model):
     44     __tablename__ = "Ingredient"
     45 
/home/Harrryj/mysite/flask_app.py in Ingredient()
     46     Ingredient_ID = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
     47     Ingredient_Name = db.Column(db.String(100))
---> 48     Ingredient_Calories = db.Column(db.Integer(100))
     49 
     50 
TypeError: object() takes no parameters
```

Any help would be appreciated! I know I'm missing something

Answer (score 1):

Original author of the tutorial here.   The problem is that you have

```
Ingredient_Calories = db.Column(db.Integer(100))
```

in the line that's highlighted.   An integer doesn't have a size, so you should do this instead:

```
Ingredient_Calories = db.Column(db.Integer)
```

As an aside, your timing is excellent.  I've just written a [second part to the tutorial](https://blog.pythonanywhere.com/158/), which includes adding an extra table, so you might find other useful stuff there.

Comment: Worked! Thanks so much :)